# React Native auth flow Hide/Show Sections/Components in Ecommerce App Before and After Login

Tags: android, react-native

I am building a eCommerce app using react native. I created root navigation stack before and after login but the problem is there are common pages for example: a logged in user can view Home screen with more sections and components however unregistered user can view same screen with less sections. How it can be managed with the best performance? should create same page two times and put each one in createStack navigator?

Comment: We can do it within the same component by having a flag variable like `isLoggedIn`. By the flag, we can hide/show the component

Comment: Ok Kumar, in this way in what stack should put the home screen in loggedIn stack?

Comment: Gaurav has added a comment which shows how can we do it in this way. Please upvote the comment and Gaurav's answer if this helps <3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont have to create 2 pages, that would be repetative and also not a good practice . You can have a flag named mostly `userLoggedIn` which initially will be false and after login you can set it to be `true`. If you are using redux it would be very easy since you need this in almost all pages.

But if you are not using, still you can achieve via AsyncStorage where you can set like `AsyncStorage.setItem('userLoggedIn','true');` after user logins.

And in the component where you want suppose Home ,

```
constructor(props){
this.state={
isLoggedIn:'false'
}
}
componentDidMount(){
let isLoggedIn = AsyncStorage.getItem('userLoggedIn'); 

this.setState({isLoggedIn:isLoggedIn});
}

render(){

return(

{this.state.isLoggedIn == 'true'? <SHowProfile />:<View />}
{this.state.isLoggedIn == 'true'? <ShowMenu />:<View />}
)

}
```

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts

Comment: ok thanks bro, but if there are many pages and in each page many conditions it is a good practice? especially when using states?

Comment: thats why redux is apt for that, and yes its a better practice than creating 2 screens coz it will increase redundency and num of lines of code